# asus smart gesture not working

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, scrolling

I have a Asus N55S laptop (I am running Windows).

I have installed the smart Asus gesture driver and the icon is on the taskbar.

I had many problems trying to find it in the beginning and trying to install it, but in the end I found the drivers here:

http://www.driverscape.com/manufacturers/asus/laptops-desktops/n55sf/541

My problem is that scrolling down doesn't work.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: ASUS website has a version that supports Windoss 10 you should try using that

Comment: that the driver i install it's working cause i cand find the icon ... but it's not scrolling